# Field Form doesn't update selected value in option

Tags: reactjs, react-final-form, final-form

I've React Final Form in my project. I have a problem with updating the displayed `option` in `select`. The entire form works fine, but doesn't change the display value.

```
function App() {
  const [selectValue, setSelectValue] = useState();

return (
    <Form
      onSubmit={onSubmit}
      initialValues={{}}
      render={({ handleSubmit, form, submitting, pristine, values }) => (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <label>Dish type</label>
            <Field
              name="type"
              component="select"
              defaultValue={selectValue}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}
              required
            >
              <option value="" />
              <option value="pizza">pizza</option>
              <option value="soup">soup</option>
              <option value="sandwich">sandwich</option>
            </Field>
          </div>
        </form>
      )}
    />
  );
```

On live-server `option` does not change its value. Displayed value is the same as the first time I selected.

Comment: Hello, welcome to stackoverflow, may you please be clear on your question.

Comment: On live-server 'option' does not change its 'value'. Displayed value is the same as the first time I selected.

Comment: What if you change `Field` to the regular html `select` tag

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the regular html `select`.

```
<select value={selectValue}
              onChange={(e) => setSelectValue(e.target.value)}
              required
            >
              <option value="" />
              <option value="pizza">pizza</option>
              <option value="soup">soup</option>
              <option value="sandwich">sandwich</option></select>
```

Comment: it's working, but I've to use React Final Form, where u're using <Field>